# Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: failed to write prefs file. selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm attempting to run Selenium grid with google chrome extensions in docker, but my code ran into an error.

code runs perfectly localy but when i try to start it via docker i got an error.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/dev/shm/sale")
unpacked_extension_path = '/dev/shm/sale/Default/Extensions/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/10.16.1_0'
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension={}'.format(unpacked_extension_path))
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub', options=chrome_options)
```

here is my docker-compose file

```
sale_selenium:
    container_name: sale_selenium
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:103.0.5060.53
    volumes:
      - ../mounts/Extensions:/dev/shm/sale/Default/Extensions
    networks:
      - sale_network
    expose:
      - 4444
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.40'
          memory: '2500M'
```

Comment: Update the question with the error tracelogs.